# How to use Karma Jasmine "toHaveBeenCalledWith" an Array?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, angular7, karma-jasmine

I have a unit test like so:

```
it('should be successful', fakeAsync(() =>
  component.doSomething();
  let myObj = {
    abc: 'test1',
    dfg: 'test2'
  }
  let myArray: Array<AnObject> = [myObj];
  expect(storage.set).toHaveBeenCalledWith('storedThing', myArray);
));
```

This is the doSomething method being called:

```
myArray: Array<AnObject>;

doSomething(): void {
  let myObj = {
    abc: 'test1',
    dfg: 'test2'
  }
  myArray.push(myObj);
  this.storage.set('storedThing', myArray);
}
```

But when I run, I get the following error:

> Expected spy set to have been called with [ 'storedThing', [ Object ]
>   ] but actual calls were [ 'storedThing', Array ].

What am I doing wrong?